# How do I submit contents of a list (modified by jQuery) in HTML?

Tags: jquery, post, attr, selected

I implemented a select from-to pair of lists on a page and added add/remove buttons.
the jQuery javascript is simple and works well:

```
function add(){
    $('#pool option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#chosen').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
function remove(){
    $('#chosen option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#pool').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I want to submit the contents of the 'chosen' list to my server.

I tried to place the lists in a form.  When I submit the form, the server receives nothing unless I actually selected the items in the 'chosen' list.

Here is a snippet:
< form action="URL" method="POST" onsubmit="preSubmit();" >...

```
function preSubmit(){
$('#chosen').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});
};
```

Did not work!
How can I get the items in the 'chosen' list delivered to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).attr("selected","selected");` can only apply to one `option` at a time. You are effectively overriding it in every step of your loop.

You have not provided enough of your html, but this should be more or less what you need:

```
function preSubmit()
{
    var form = $('#chosen').closest('form');

    $('#chosen option').each(function()
    {
        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + $(this).val() + '" value="' + $(this).text() + '" />');
    });
};
```

**P.S.** Consider caching your selectors.

On a side note, you should be using `prop` instead of `attr` (if you're using a recent version of jQuery).

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, I took the most important part of your answer which is to include 'option' in the selector.  I kept the original code (which is to turn the selected attribute on) and it worked. I will now look into the advantage of adding corresponding hidden fields as per your suggestion.